# Always in the shit; only the depth changes

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, differences

I came across this humorous Latin phrase on social media, rendered as:

> *Sumus semper in excretum, sed alta variat*

...but when I searched it, I realised there was a more common rendering of it:

> *Semper in excretia, sumus solim profundum variat*

Which of these more accurately conveys the intended meaning in the original Latin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither is good Latin. The first one:

> Sumus semper in excretum, sed alta variat

... translates as:

> We are always in [excretum], but [alta] changes.

*Excretum* is the accusative of the supine of *excerno* 'to separate'; presumably *excrementum* is meant, but it should at least be in the ablative—*excremento*. (The English verb *excrete* does derive from *excretum*, but that's a late development.) *Alta* is some form of the adjective *altus* 'high, deep'; a noun is required, like *altitudo*, in the nominative as it's the subject of *variat*. (Latin doesn't distinguish between depth and height; they're two aspects of a single concept to a Roman.)

The corrected sentence is then:

> Sumus semper in excremento, sed altitudo variat.

The second sentence:

> Semper in excretia, sumus solim profundum variat

... translates as:

> Always in [excretia], we are [solim] the depth changes.

*Excretia* isn't a word at all, and again *excremento* is meant. The comma is presumably misplaced, with the *sumus* belonging to the first part of the sentence. *Solim* is not a word either; it's probably a typo for the adverb *solum* 'only', possibly with contamination from *olim* 'then, often' to give it a more adverby feel. *Profundum* does mean 'depth' but not in the sense intended; it means 'the depth' in the sense of 'the abyss'. Again *altitudo* is the better choice.

The corrected sentence:

> Semper in excremento sumus, solum altitudo variat.

The word order doesn't really mean anything in this case, and the only difference between the two corrected sentences is *sed* 'but' versus *solum* 'only'. If you want to match your English sentence closely, go with *solum* and omit *sumus*.

Really, though, this may be one of those things where the deliberately bad Latin is considered part of the charm, like "Nolite te bastardes carborundorum" or "Semper ubi sub ubi".

Comment: I think I'd prefer sola over solum, but I've always liked adjectives more than adverbs in Latin.

Comment: According to OLD, except in a few specific contexts, variare is transitive, and if you want it to mean 'vary' (i.e., 'become different') here, you would need to use the passive variatur (or, I suppose, the reflexive se variat).

Comment: @cnread I don't know why the OLD claims that because it's not true.

Comment: Sorry, either I misread 'pass. **or intr.**' in def. 3b of the OLD entry, or my brain just completely failed to register the 'or intr.' part. I myself would still go for the passive, but this is your translation and does appear to be grammatically correct after all.

Comment: Well, that's some profound shit